# Internet Explorer with High Security Settings Kills Session Immediately

Tags: internet-explorer, session, internet-explorer-11, session-state

We've got a web app on a secure server, and as recent as the last few days, when clients login to the web app with IE 11, they immediately get sent to the session timed out page.

We've tested with the IE security settings, and this is only happening when the settings are set to High. The client uses IE company wide and the settings are set to High as per their company policy.

The workaround on the clientside is to add our site as a trusted site, but that would require a monumental effort on the client's part to implement.

Is there a way to fix this on the server side?

Comment: About what web app are you talking about. Do you got their adress or test adress ??